# How to vertical align text

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs like this

```
<div class='unit'>number1</div>
<div class='unit'>number2</div>
<div class='unit'>number3</div>
```

css

```
.unit{
  border: solid 2px yellow;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I want to vertical align my contents for every unit so I used css above. However, I can only horizontally center the texts not vertical. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: *vertical align my contents for every unit*. Can you clarify this sentence. As it stands I don't understand

Comment: The accepted answer here looks like a pretty good explanation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it

```
.unit{
  border: solid 2px yellow;
  display:table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;   
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Working here- http://jsfiddle.net/kfE4Z/**

Answer (score -1):

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

You can create content div inside outer box then if you dont mind using table-cell you can use it

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/bsRCh/4/)

Comment: Which is already stated in the original CSS.